# Импортирование данных * .xlsx через ExcelDataReader с количеством затронутых записей 0

Tags: c#

использую библиотеки ExcelDataReader и ExcelDataReader.DataSet для чтения более 1700 строк из xlsx-файла. В конце концов, записи не читаются. Однако, если мы ограничим число строк до 9 - все данные строк будут прочитаны правильно. Вот код:

```
private IEnumerable<T> ParseImportSourceFile<T>(string fileName, byte[] file) where T : CsvClassMap
{
    IEnumerable<T> records = null;

    var extensionEnd = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
    switch (Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower())
    {
        case ".csv":                    
            break;
        case ".xls":
        case ".xlsx":
        case ".ods":
            records = new List<T>();

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(file);
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
            var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(streamReader.BaseStream);
            if (extensionEnd == ".xlsx")
            {
                reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(streamReader.BaseStream);
                //reader.
            }
              //reader.AsDataSet().
            try
            {

                var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                {
                    UseColumnDataType = true,
                    ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                    {
                        EmptyColumnNamePrefix = "Column",
                        UseHeaderRow = true,
                    }
                });

                if (result.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    var tbl = result.Tables[0];
                    //grab column names into array
                    var columns = new DataColumn[tbl.Columns.Count];
                    tbl.Columns.CopyTo(columns, 0);

                    //grab properties of T class
                    var tType = typeof(T);
                    var properties = tType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                    for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //one row one record... create an instance for each row
                        var row = tbl.Rows[i];
                        var record = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                        //read all columns and try set valid property
                        foreach (var col in columns)
                        {
                            var prop = properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == col.ColumnName ||
                                                                    (x.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>() != null && x.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name == col.ColumnName));

                            if (prop != null && prop.CanWrite)
                            {
                                //
                                var sourceValue = row[col.ColumnName];
                                if(!(sourceValue is DBNull))
                                    prop.SetValue(record, Parse(prop.PropertyType, sourceValue.ToString()));
                            }
                        }

                        ((IList<T>)records).Add(record);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null) reader.Dispose();
                if (streamReader != null) streamReader.Dispose();
                if (memoryStream != null) memoryStream.Dispose();
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new ImportException("Template is not valid.");
    }

    return records;
}
```

Я использую метод CreateOpenXmlReader для файла xlsx, как это было предложено в stackoverflow. tbl.Rows.Count - ноль - из более чем 1700 строк в файле xlsx. Пожалуйста помогите

Comment: А количество столбцов в таблице случайно не равно 9 или 10?

Comment: 36 столбцов в таблице

Comment: Блок try видно, а где catch? Может быть какое-либо исключение выбрасывается?

Comment: Нет, не вызывается исключение

Comment: Использование ExcelDataReader  принципиально?

Comment: Да, не имею возможность  и право заменить.

Comment: Что самое интересное, входной файл в xlsx формате. после сохранения в Libreoffice в формате xlsx меняет размер в сторону уменьшения, количество строк остается тоже самое. Однако, файл читается и заполняется DataSet

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91956/discussion-between-xelanimed-and-roman-ieromenko).